# How to solve error C4996 when calling npx react-native run-windows?

Tags: react-native-windows

I created a new application using react native for windows. I followed the instructions on the microsoft website, but when I call the command npx react-native run-windows an error occurs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQeRQ.png)

Tried all the options on stackoverflow. Changed versions of react-native-windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Those who have encountered a similar problem will understand everything. I have already added the solution as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the fmt 8.00 library. Microsoft just made a commit to the project yesterday and replaced it with fmt 10.1.0. But it's not in npm yet. Therefore, before the npx react-native run-windows command, you need to change the following lines in the Directory.Build.props file:

```
<FmtVersion>10.1.0</FmtVersion>
<FmtCommitHash>ca2e3685b160617d3d95fcd9e789c4e06ca88</FmtCommitHash>
```